# Ticket to Ride "Longest Path of Routes"

Tags: ticket-to-ride

I understand that the longest route means the most number of continuous trains, but does continuous mean "connected?"  In other words, are spur routes included as long as they are connected to the main route?

Comment: Right, it's not "has placed the most routes that are pairwise connected to another of your routes."

Comment: I think the problem is that “continuous” is not the clearest word to use. I was going to quote the rule book in my answer, but it turns out it really doesn’t make it explicit. It just relies on common English understanding of “continuous route”.

Answer (score 8):

Spurs are not included.<sup>[1]</sup> Being connected is not sufficient; the routes must form a continuous path.

---

The rules say

> The player who has the Longest Continuous Path of routes receives this special bonus card and adds 10 points to his score. When evaluating and comparing path lengths, only take into account continuous lines of plastic trains of the same color. A continuous path may include loops, and pass through the same city several times, but a given plastic train may never be used twice in the same continuous path. In the case of a tie for the longest path, all tied players score the 10 point bonus

Let's use the following network as an example:

```
   A - - B                        -, |, \, / = train
          \
           \
            C - - D - - E
            |
            |
            F
```

How many trains are in the longest continuous path? Obviously, it's at least 8 (A-B, B-C, C-D, D-E). Is there a way of including the two in C-F without jumping (not continuous) or revisiting a route (explicitly disallowed)?

- If you travel along the path A-B-C-D-E, you'd need to jump or backtrack to visit C-F.
- If you travel along the path A-B-C-F, you'd need to jump or backtrack to visit C-D.
- If you travel along the path F-C-D-E, you'd need to jump or backtrack to visit B-C.

So no. The longest continuous path consists of just the eight trains along those four routes.

This is confirmed through play with multiple groups and through use of the official electronic version.

Note that at least one map (Asia) awards points for largest network, which includes forks (though this counts cities rather than routes).

---

1. Unless you can loop back. For example, the following has a continuous path of 10 trains (A-B-D-E-C):

   ```
   A - - B - - C
        / \
       /   \
      D - - E
   ```

Comment: So it's not the number of trains but the number of routes?

Comment: I bought the digital edition for my kid yesterday, but he hasn't had a chance to play. Would be a great way to check!

Comment: It is the number of trains. "longest" means you count length, meaning number of trains.

Comment: @ikegami Sawtaytoes questions whether it's trains or number of routes. I answered it's number of trains.

Comment: "Longest path of routes" when routes have lengths (in trains) means the same as "longest path of routes measured in trains".

Comment: @L. Scott Johnson, No, that not how things work. I mean, sometimes it works that way, sometimes it doesn't. Consider a line of people. I ask how long the line is. You might say there's 10 people in line. Or you might say there's a one hour wait. The rules are ambiguous. BUT. You happen to have the right answer. I'm adjusting the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes [Number of trains](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/2151/2880). Questions edited for clarity.

Comment: uh, I edited my *answer*, not the question.

Answer (score 4):

"Continuous" means a line starting at one end and ending at another end; branching paths will not help at all. A "continuous path" means that you can travel along that path without backtracking or skipping around; with a branch/fork in your trains you wouldn't be able to go along all of those trains without backtracking or skipping. So you only count the longest branch of a fork.

You can find more discussion with the same answer [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/426572/how-do-you-determine-longest-route).

Answer (score -1):

1. I originally thought longest route meant "count the trains", but a route is defined as connecting points A and B.
2. In the digital version, loops count too as part of your continuous route.

[image: Ticket to Ride map]
[image: longest continuous path]

This follows what's in the rules for Ticket to Ride Europe:

> When evaluating and comparing path lengths, only take into account continuous lines of plastic trains of the same color. **A continuous path may include loops,** and pass through the same city several times, but a given plastic train may never be used twice in the same continuous path. Stations, and the opponents’ routes they may provide access to, do not count for the purpose of computing paths and claiming the longest one. If several players are tied for the longest path, they each receive the 10 point bonus from the European Express card.

Comment: You do count trains: but only the trains in the continuous path of routes. loops are OK if they form part of that longest continuous path.